# pl/sql - insert in two tables in one time

Tags: plsql

I have got three tables in my oracle database

- `my_bet` which includes bets
- `t_match` which includes matches which I bet on
- third table is intersection table between the two, with two columns `bet_id` and `match_id`.

In tables `my_bet` and `t_match`, I have sequences, which generates IDs. There is a problem: I want to create a bet, which includes for example three matches. How can I insert into both tables, by procedure, that sequence created for just one ID in `my_bet` table. But now it generates three new IDs in `t_match` table ?

I don t know how to better to describe my problem, sorry! I hope you will help me.

This is my data model - table t_my_bets

```
Name          Null?    Type   
------------- -------- ------ 
BET_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER 
BET_KURZ               NUMBER 
BET_WIN                NUMBER 
FK_BET_STATUS          NUMBER 
BET_MONEY              NUMBER 
BET_DATE               DATE

j_t_bet_match - is join table t_my_bets and t_match

Name     Null? Type   
-------- ----- ------ 
BET_ID         NUMBER 
MATCH_ID       NUMBER

and finally t_match

Name             Null?    Type          
---------------- -------- ------------- 
MATCH_ID         NOT NULL NUMBER        
MATCH_NAME                VARCHAR2(400) 
MATCH_RESULT              VARCHAR2(20)  
MATCH_KURZ                NUMBER        
MATCH_TIP                 VARCHAR2(10)  
MATCH_LEAGUE              VARCHAR2(50)  
MATCH_SPORT               NUMBER        
MATCH_BET_STATUS          NUMBER
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate with some example. That will be good/.

Comment: It's a question of Data Modeling. Assuming that we have the following tables: BET, MATCH and LINK (which links the records of BET and MATCH). I would do the following: BET(column ID, generated as a sequence), MATCH (column ID, generated as a sequence), LINK (column ID, generated as a sequence and a PK (Primary Key), column GROUP_ID, generated as a sequence, but only once per group). That column LINK.GROUP_ID is the key to your issue. You should generate it once per group, for instance - one BET record, having three MATCH records - these four records should have the same GROUP_ID.

Comment: My last comment describes a possible solution, if I understood the problem correctly If not - that's another story, but as far as I can see - it's about grouping records and letting know the third table how they are grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Generating IDs in the match table seems like a broken workflow. Matches should be reference data, because they must exist before a bet can be placed on them.

Your question lacks too many details for us to provide anything like a complete solution but here is a sketch. It uses a collection to pass in the IDs of the matches you want to place a bet on. Presumably you have other columns in `my_bet` which need populating, and so need to be passed as parameters, but you haven't said what they are so you'll have to fill those in for yourself.

```
 create or replace procedure place_bets
      ( p_matches in sys.ODCINUMBERLIST)
 is
     v_bet_id number;
 begin
     insert into my_bet (bet_id) 
     values (bet_id_seq.nextval) -- or whatever your sequence is called
     returning bet id into v_bet_id;

     insert into bet_matches -- or whatever your third table is called
       ( bet_id, match_id)
     select v_bet_id, t.column_value
     from table(p_matches);
end;
/
```

So, the first INSERT creates the BET record; it uses the RETURNING clause to capture the assigned `bet_id`. The second INSERT creates a record for each entry in the collection of `match_id`s, linking them to the `bet_id`.

Comment: and what is p_matches in your argumnet ? Thank you

Comment: `p_matches` is a collection of `match_id` values. As I said in my answer you have provided almost *no details* about your data model or business rules, as I've made up some, to frame an example.